# How to concat query result of top N records from a group in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following query which gives the count of name grouped by user id in desc order. I have reached so far but cant go beyond that. I would like to concat the name column of top 2 records per user.

The Query so far is:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       IF(@grp = t.user_id, @rowno := @rowno + 1, @rowno := 1) AS rowno, 
       @grp := t.user_id AS u_id 
FROM   (SELECT notes.user_id, 
               t.name        name, 
               Count(t.name) ct 
        FROM   notes 
               INNER JOIN tags t 
                       ON notes.id = t.note_id 
        GROUP  BY notes.user_id, 
                  t.name 
        ORDER  BY notes.user_id, 
                  Count(t.name) DESC) t;
```

It gives the following result:

```
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| user_id | name       | ct | rowno | uid |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 282     | realifex   | 1  | 1     | 282 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 282     | clear      | 1  | 2     | 282 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 282     | thinking   | 1  | 3     | 282 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 282     | refreshing | 1  | 4     | 282 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 285     | solid      | 2  | 1     | 285 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 285     | clear      | 1  | 2     | 285 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 285     | thinking   | 1  | 3     | 285 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 287     | holidays   | 3  | 1     | 287 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 287     | Larry      | 3  | 2     | 287 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 287     | travel     | 2  | 3     | 287 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
| 287     | thinking   | 1  | 4     | 287 |
+---------+------------+----+-------+-----+
```

I am trying to concat the top 2 results into one column from every user group like this:

```
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | name           |
+---------+----------------+
| 282     | realifex,clear |
+---------+----------------+
| 285     | solid,   clear |
+---------+----------------+
| 287     | Larry,travel   |
+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ue `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT group_id, group_concat(name order by rn) as names
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             (@rn := IF(@grp = t.user_id, @rowno := @rowno + 1, 
                        IF(@grp := t.user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             )  as rn
      FROM (SELECT n.user_id, t.name, n.name,  Count(t.name) ct 
            FROM notes n INNER JOIN
                 tags t 
                 ON notes.id = t.note_id 
            GROUP BY n.user_id,  t.name 
            ORDER BY n.user_id, Count(t.name) DESC
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @grp := -1) params
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Note:

- The expression for `@rn` and `@grp` is a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so a single expression is the only way to safely assign the two variables.
- The variables are initialized.
- The `WHERE` clause is where the "top 2" is determined.

Comment: Hey @Gordon thanks for the answer but I am facing syntax problem with it. Tried to solve it but no luck. facing following error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 
                         IF(@grp := t.user_id, 1, 1)
                         ' at line 4

Comment: @Prem . . . There was an extra argument to `if()` on the previous line.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the effort and help but I have tweaked the query a bit to make it run and it's running but the outcome is not the same.
The query result is not concatenated and it has only one name instead of top two results per group.
| 282     | realifex|
| 285     | solid |
| 287     | Larry  |

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I was able to figure out the whole  query and got the result. Thank you again.